# bz2 issue when installing Python 2.6.6 on Cent OS 5.8

Tags: python, installation, bzip2

I installed bzip2, bzip2-devel & bzip2-libs using the following command:

```
yum install bzip2 bzip2-devel bzip2-libs
```

Installation proceeded with to warning or error.

After this step, I installed Python 2.6.6 using the following commands (note: I must install it this way and not using yum):

```
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.6/Python-2.6.6.tgz
tar -xzvf Python-2.6.6.tgz
cd Python-2.6.6
./configure
make
make install
```

But on "make" step, I got the following error:

> Failed to build these modules: bz2

I tried installing Mercurial 2.0.2 afterward but got the following error:

> Couldn't import standard bz2 (incomplete Python install).

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong here?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem by adding **`--enable-shared`** option when configuring Python.

```
./configure --enable-shared
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have mixed installation of Python. In my case, I had two installations

`/usr/local/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/python` where by default it was using first one.

So I did:
`rm  /usr/bin/python` and it worked.

Or

You can also change the priority of `which python` in your $PATH.